# article:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(2n-1)

Tags: css

Can somebody explain me what this do? because i don't get the exactly clue anymore.

```
article:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(2n-1)
```

Hope somebody can say if it's good or not.

let me know people!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a CSS selector that selects the odd p tags (1st, 3rd, ...) that are direct children of an article tag that is the 3rd child of any parent element.

EDIT: Here is a JSFiddle that confirms what I have said above:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HLtRD/)

Answer (score 0):

Any p tag that is an odd child element of an article tag that is the third child element of its parent. [doc-nth child](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) [child-combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators)